# Escrevendo no arquivo JSON com javascript

Tags: javascript, banco-de-dados, json

Estou tentando manipular um arquivo json vazio:

```
const fs = require('fs')

// lendo o arquivo JSON
const DB = require('./DB.json')

// Definindo o novo user
let user = {
    name:'new user',
    age: 30,
    language: ['Javascript', 'PHP', 'Pytohn']
};

// adicionando novos dados ao usuario
DB.pusher(user)

// Escrevendo o aqrquivo
fs.writeFile('DB.json', JSON.stringify(DB), err => {
    //checando erros
    if (err) return err;
    
    console.log('Gravado');
})
```

aparece o seguinte erro throw err;

Comment: Qual é a mensagem de erro?

Comment: Onde está `DB.pusher(user)` faça `DB.push(user)` e considere usar um linter.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

O erro é um erro de sintaxe e está no seu *DB.pusher(user)*, você esta usando `pusher` ao invés de `push` para adicionar um novo valor no array. Segue um exemplo:

Considerando o seguinte DB.json

```
{
    "users": [
        {
            "name": "old user",
            "age": 18,
            "language": [
                "Ruby",
                "C"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

O correto para adicionar um novo objeto nesse array "users", seria:

```
const fs = require('fs')
const DB = require('./DB.json')

let user = {
    name: 'new user2',
    age: 30,
    language: ['Javascript', 'PHP', 'Pytohn']
};

DB.users.push(user);

fs.writeFile('DB.json', JSON.stringify(DB), err => {
    //checando erros
    if (err) return err;

    console.log('Gravado');
})
```

Ao executar o código acima, seu DB.json passa a ser:

```
{
    "users": [
        {
            "name": "old user",
            "age": 18,
            "language": [
                "Ruby",
                "C"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "new user2",
            "age": 30,
            "language": [
                "Javascript",
                "PHP",
                "Pytohn"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Não responda sobre erros de sintaxe. É pressuposto do site que as perguntas venham lives de erros de sintaxe. Faça no máximo uma orientação por comentários. Correção de erros de sintaxe é relevante apenas para quem errou e são profícuas, se proliferam soterrando as perguntas relevantes. Se começarmos acolher esse tipo de pergunta os sistemas de busca começaram apontar apenas para erros de sintaxe que ajudam unicamente o autor da pergunta e perguntas de relevância coletiva cada vez mais serão empurrados para o fim da pesquisa, como já está acontecendo.

Comment: Entendo, mas amigo, outra questão é que ele também precisa acessar o array users dentro do JSON, ou seja, não se trata apenas da sintaxe do push, talvez o json dele também esteja errado, com esse exemplo pode ficar mais simples para iniciantes conseguirem encontrar um erro que é bastante comum, mas que muitas vezes deixa o estudante travado. Acredito que a explicação do meu post pode resolver outros erros e dúvidas como a de acesso ao JSON e escrita, pois está bem mais visual e explicativo que um comentário que é limitado por chars.

Comment: Lembrando que com mais uns pontinhos pode ajudar individual no campo de comentários, aí ajuda o autor da pergunta, mas não produz ruído na indexação. Em casos que a pergunta tenha como ser salva (aqui não é bem o caso), é importante ajudar o autor a fornecer um [mcve] do problema, para depois resolver. Dessa forma, outros usuários com problema similar encontrarão solução. Se a pergunta não deixa claro o lugar do erro, por melhor que fosse a resposta, não seria encontrada por outros precisando de solução (é apenas uma sugestão. Cada um faz como quer, e a comunidade avalia como acha que deve).